# How to recompute observable once for a single event loop tick?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a use case where I have one observable shared across multiple observables where finally those 2 observable merged into a single one.

The issue is, whenever I click the document, I get subscription callback called twice, but I need it to be called once containing the last value:

```js
import { fromEvent, of, combineLatest } from "rxjs";
import { map, switchMap, startWith } from "rxjs/operators";

const sharedState$ = fromEvent(document, "click").pipe(
  map((event) => event.clientX),
  startWith(0)
);

const stateA$ = of(5).pipe(
  switchMap((a) => sharedState$.pipe(map((x) => x + a)))
);
const stateB$ = of(7).pipe(
  switchMap((b) => sharedState$.pipe(map((x) => x + b)))
);

const result$ = combineLatest([stateA$, stateB$]).pipe(map(([a, b]) => a + b));

result$.subscribe(console.log);
```

Here it is the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-water-kg5g2?file=/src/index.js) for the convenience:

Technically, I understand why it's happening. First `sharedState$` update is propagated to `stateA$` and therefore the whole `result$` is recomputed. And next the same thing is happening with `stateB$`.

But both these updates are happening synchronously one immediately after another in a single event loop tick, which make sense to result in a single subscriber notification of `result$` stream.

Finally, I came up applying `debounceTime(0)` operator on the `result$` stream, which solved the problem. But I have a feeling that it's more a workaround than the actual solution:

```js
// works, but I'm not sure whether it's the right way
const result$ = combineLatest([stateA$, stateB$]).pipe(
  map(([a, b]) => a + b),
  debounceTime(0)
);
```

What's the idiomatic way of handling such things?

PS. Obviously, for that specific use-case it can be solved differently, which will result in a single subscriber call, but my real use case is quite complicated and unfortunately the pieces being merged together into a final observable composed dynamically and can include the same observable inside.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve the issue you mentioned:

```
import { zip } from "rxjs";
import { distinctUntilChanged } from "rxjs/operators";


const result$ = zip([stateA$, stateB$]).pipe(map(([a, b]) => a + b), distinctUntilChanged());
```

For the cases where we need to trigger when any observable emits:

Just adding an operator to your initial solution, so it will not emit multiple times on clicking the same point.

```
const result$ = combineLatest([stateA$, stateB$]).pipe(
  map(([a, b]) => a + b),
  debounceTime(0),
  distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

Comment: Interesting... That almost solves the issue. However there might be the case when we combine these observables with something which doesn't emits the value, for example - `zip([stateA$, stateB$, somethingElse$])`. In that case `zip` won't be triggered if only `stateA$` and `stateB$` are updated, it will wait for the update from `somethingElse$` as well.

Would be great to have a solution where we recompute when either inputs of `zip` emits not necessarily all of them.

Sorry for not mentioning that initially

Comment: @aiven715 Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you. That almost makes sense. Actually `distinctUntilChanged` is not needed since I do not mind having the same results twice if they came at a different time. However `debounceTime(0)` function turns stream from being sync to async which makes impossible to get the result of a stream's first subscription in the same synchronous execution stack.